# SoapUI - REST Mocking with Query Parameter

Tags: rest, unit-testing, mocking, soapui

I have several mocks with responses.
But for some of them I want to create response based on additional query parameter.
For example:
I have mock for REST request such as "GET /order/item" and it works fine.
But I tried to create mock for "GET /order/item?status=queued" and created response for it, but I get the same response as for "GET /order/item" when I test it out.

Is it possible to create REST Mock with Query in SoapUI Pro (5.1.2)?

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add script dispatch to your mock action `GET /order/item` as it is shown on below picture:
[image]
Additionally, You have to define two MockResponse for above mock action:

- `queuedItem`
- `item`

Then the script will dispatch to `queuedItem` if http parameter `status = queued`

Comment: I followed your instruction @snieguu but, I'm getting 404 error, "This localhost page can’t be found". Am i missing anything? Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

```
if("queued".equals(mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getParameter("status"))) {
  log.info("queued");
  mockRequest.getHttpResponse().getWriter().write("queued");
} else {
  log.info("nope");
  mockRequest.getHttpResponse().getWriter().write("nope");  
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more context to your code? Just the code is not informative enough.